# Drupal Commerce 1: Not getting shipping methods returned

Tags: commerce, hooks

I have to rewrite our company's ecommerce modules to work with our new service, converting it from XML to REST. I have a function that implements hook_commerce_shipping_service_info()

```
/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_shipping_service_info().
 */
function mymodule_shipping_commerce_shipping_service_info() {

  $shipping_services = array();


  foreach ($_SESSION[SHIPPING_METHODS] as $shipping_object) {

    $shipping_services[$shipping_object->{"<Id>k__BackingField"}] = array(
      'title' => $shipping_object->{"<Name>k__BackingField"},
      'description' => "Ship with " . $shipping_object->{'<Name>k__BackingField'},
      'display_title' => $shipping_object->{'<Name>k__BackingField'},
      'shipping_method' => 'mymodule_shipping_method',
      'price_component' => 'shipping',
      'callbacks' => array(
        'rate' => 'mymodule_shipping_service_rate',
        'details_form' => 'mymodule_shipping_service_details_form',
        'details_form_validate' => 'mymodule_shipping_service_details_form_validate',
        'details_form_submit' => 'mymodule_shipping_service_details_form_submit',
      ),
    );;
  }

  return $shipping_services;

}
```

which gets a list of shipping from our internal service. I appears to work fine and mimics what was once hardcoded as options but it doesn't seem to perform the callbacks.

Each time I try to get shipping via the site, the shipping page comes back with no shipping methods found despite the array being filled with 3 options:

```
[
   "1":[
      "title":"UPS Ground",
      "description":"Ship with UPS Ground",
      "display_title":"UPS Ground",
      "shipping_method":"mymodule_shipping_method",
      "price_component":"shipping",
      "callbacks":[
         "rate":"mymodule_shipping_service_rate",
         "details_form":"mymodule_shipping_service_details_form",
         "details_form_validate":"mymodule_shipping_service_details_form_validate",
         "details_form_submit":"mymodule_shipping_service_details_form_submit"
      ]
   ],
...
]
```

I added watchdog to the mymodule_shipping_service_rate to see if it was running so I can see where the issue might be but the watchdog is never registered in my Recent Log Messages which leads me to believe that somehow those callbacks are not firing.

I am absolutely perplexed why the shipping options pane keeps coming up empty. Anything glaring wrong? Thanks!

Comment: There is no `Commerce 1` for D8... or are you on D7 now?

Comment: Yes, sorry, C1 for D7. I am currently trying to covert our old system as well as build the new D8 version

Comment: Can I add the 'rate' to the main array and just call the function that returns the values? i.e  "price_component":"shipping", "rate" => srs_shipping_service_rate($info)?

Comment: The hook function `mymodule_shipping_commerce...` should be `mymodule_commerce...` or was that an error you made when switch to mymodule name?

Comment: Opps, yes, the actual module is mymodel_shipping_ and that function seems to be 'working fine' as in it fires and creates the array of options. Problem is that nothing seems to be called after and the result is empty. When they were hard coded, it seems to work fine.

Comment: I reverted back to the static array and the shipping rates is being called. So I can't created that dynamically since the call backs aren't called then, correct?

Comment: Correct, inspect the values of the parameter variables of those callback functions. Maybe there is something there that allows you to distinguish.